# nginx location with regular expression

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

i have the nginx server as reverse proxy for apache. just trying to have multiple locations with reg expressions but fail.

I want to set the expires header for all jpg's and png's but not for images in a specific folder

currently

```
location ~* ^(?!/login/)(.*)\.(jpg|png)$ { expires 30d; }
```

this works with request from

http://example.com/test/image.jpg

but not working with

http://example.com/login/image.jpg

also tried with several location

```
location ~ ^/login/$ { break; }

location ~* \.(jpg|png)$ { expires 30d; }
```

but not working. I also tried nested location but same problem, nothing work. Can anyone help me?

Thanks and kind regards, Tom

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You say that you want to set header for files except specific folder. And the `location ~* ^(?!/login/)(.*)\.(jpg|png)$ { expires 30d; }` will do exactly that. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/RTzwit/1) what it matches: Either your question is not clear or...

Comment: Your link to the online tester helped me to solve the problem. Think the problem was that there were relative and absolute paths and thus the query on the directory did not always work.

Thats how it works

location ~* ^(?!(.*)/login/)(.*)\.(jpg|png)$ { expires 30d; }

Thank you!!!!